# $ \mu_n \overset{w}{\longrightarrow} \delta_0 $ $\iff$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n((-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\mu_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. I want to show that
$$
\mu_n \overset{w}{\longrightarrow} \delta_0 \quad \text{ for } \ n \to \infty \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n((-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c) = 0 \quad \text{ for every } \ \epsilon>0.
$$

---

I think the Portmanteau theorem could be used to prove this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures

More specifically that $\mu_n$ convergers weakly to $\mu$ if and only $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(A)=\mu(A)$ for every set of continuity $A$. The problem is that I'm not sure $\{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c\colon \epsilon >0\}$ exhausts all sets of continuity for $\delta_0$. Can anyone help me see if it does? Or alternatively point me in a different direction to prove this.

---

**Bonus:** I still believe the result should hold if $(\mu_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of *finite* measures instead. Can we from probability measures get the result using some kind of scaling or a similar technique?

Comment: It's an if and only if. You don't need it to exhaust all. If $\mu_n\to\mu$, then $\lim_n \mu_n(A) = \mu(A)$ for all sets of continuity $A$. If $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ is a set of continuity, then this is guaranteed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part? It seems that one would have to check it for $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\setminus \{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c\colon \epsilon >0\} $ continuity set. In other words cases other than "$\epsilon$-tails".

Comment: You may use the version of the Portmanteau that uses open sets.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The condition for open sets is only with liminf (and besides $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)^c$ is closed so it would be the limsup condition).